# How do I extract links from a web page using scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

This is my seed URL:

```
http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_0?rh=n%3A133140011%2Cn%3A%21133141011%2Cn%3A154606011%2Cn%3A668010011%2Cn%3A158591011%2Cn%3A158592011&bbn=158591011&ie=UTF8&qid=1403264414&rnid=158591011
```

How do I extract all the kindle book links from scrapy?

This is my code but I dont get the expected results:

```
class MySpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "scraper"
    allowed_domains = ["amazon.com"]
    start_urls = ["http://www.amazon.com/s/ref=sr_nr_n_0?rh=n%3A133140011%2Cn%3A%21133141011%2Cn%3A154606011%2Cn%3A668010011%2Cn%3A158591011%2Cn%3A158592011&bbn=158591011&ie=UTF8&qid=1403264414&rnid=158591011"]   

    def parse(self, response):
        hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)
        items = hxs.select('//*[@id="resultsCol"]').re('\/dp\/B00.*digital-text')
        for item in items:
            link = item.extract()
            print link
```

Comment: Have you tried this xpath? `//span[@class="lrg bold"]/../@href` Should yield you all of the hrefs for all of the books. If the list has more than just kindle books (that page only has kindle book links) then you could probably just adjust your xpath to get you the needed results.

Comment: actually I wrote an other version of my code.Im using SGML extractor to extract the links using a regex.
This is my code :http://pastebin.com/UZYNJjW4

But its not matching with the links